# "NodeAlreadySaved " error when using djangocms publishing page changes

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, django-cms, apache2.4

**Encounter an error when using djangocms publishing page changes.**

when I ran `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`, it returned:

```
treebeard.exceptions.NodeAlreadySaved: Attempted to add a tree node that is already in the database, referer: http://47.95.254.172/?edit
```

And when I allowed the settings.py DEBUG= True and click the 'Publish page changes' button:

```
NodeAlreadySaved at /admin/cms/page/1/en/publish/
Attempted to add a tree node that is already in the database
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://47.95.254.172/admin/cms/page/1/en/publish/
Django Version: 3.1.7
Exception Type: NodeAlreadySaved
Exception Value:    Attempted to add a tree node that is already in the database
Exception Location: /root/env1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/treebeard/mp_tree.py, line 326, in process
Python Executable:  /root/env1//bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.5
```

I have run `python manage.py cms fix-tree` but it did not work. While `python manage.py cms check` returned **10 checks successful!**.

I deployed the djangocms project with:

apache2.4.41

mod-wsgi 4.8.0

django 3.1.7

django-cms 3.8.0

The python version in venv is 3.8.5, and mod-wsgi was compiled by python3.8.5 in the venv.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Downgrade to django-treebeard version below 4.5.1, e.g. 4.4. Version 4.5.1 seems to be incompatible.

```
pip install django-treebeard==4.4
```

Comment: It works!  It has troubled me for quite a long time and I really appreciate your help!

Comment: 4.5.0 is also affected, so <4.5 should be the rule

Comment: @jsj for me 4.5.0 was not working. but 4.4 worked!

Answer (score 6):

You can also modify the `requirements.txt` file to reflect a different `django-treebeard` version that is not `4.5.1`:

```
django-treebeard>=4.0,!=4.5.1
```

Then you can run:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: 4.5.0 is also affected

Answer (score 0):

It seems this has been fixed in [version 3.10.1 of django-cms](https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/upgrade/3.10.1.html):

- Fixed django treebeard 4.5.1 compatibility [(#6988) (eeb86fd70)](https://github.com/django-cms/django-cms/pull/6988) – Aiky30